# How to structure semantic-ui folder

Tags: structure, directory, semantic-ui, theming

How to setup Semantic-Ui so an update will not destroy your sites or theme. I am new to semantic-UI and also in web development

Thank you in advance

Comment: In what way does Semantic UI "destroy" your site or theme? What updates are you referring to exactly?

Comment: I think he referring to installing Semantic UI from git repo. And his question is about if his site can be broken after he gets the updated version of Semantic UI by git update later on.

Comment: Sparrow is correct. this was my concern